# Single-click mouse operation in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows XP I had my mouse set to highlight a file or program icon by pointing, and open it with a single click. I upgraded (?) to Windows 7 a week ago and haven't found how to set my mouse to that operation. Microsoft's web site has the same lack of help the OS has on my computer.  Google search hasn't helped. Is the feature available? Do you know how to set it?

Answer (score 5):

- Open an explorer window (i.e. My
  Computer)
- press left alt, a menu will appear
- Tools > Folder Options
- 'General' Tab, 'Click item as follows' section.

Answer (score 2):

Open Windows Explorer, go to Tools, Folder Options, "Click Items as Follows".
Edit, too slow.